# Error 1064 in Stored procedure while checking if a local variable is NULL after prepared statement has set its value

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a Twitter clone using MySQL and I'm writing a stored procedure to update userfeed table of a user who just followed someone new to include all the tweets of the person whom the user has followed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `populate_userfeed_after_following`(IN username varchar(20), IN following_username varchar(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_tweet timestamp default null;
    DECLARE following_id int;
    
    SELECT id from users where username=following_username into following_id;
    
    SET @timestamp_tweet = CONCAT('SELECT timestamp FROM userfeed_', username, ' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 into', last_tweet);
    
    PREPARE timestamp_tweetQuery FROM @timestamp_tweet;
    EXECUTE timestamp_tweetQuery;
    
    IF (last_tweet is NULL) THEN
        SET @insert_statement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO userfeed_', username, '(tweet_id) SELECT id from tweets
        WHERE author=', following_id,
        ' LIMIT 200');
    ELSE
        SET @insert_statement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO userfeed_', username, '(tweet_id) SELECT id from tweets
        WHERE author=', following_id ,'and timestamp >', last_tweet);
    END IF;
    
    PREPARE insertQuery FROM @insert_statement;
    EXECUTE insertQuery; 
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE timestamp_tweetQuery;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE insertQuery;
    
END
```

I'm storing the most out-of-date timestamp in a local variable called `last_tweet` after retrieving it from the userfeed table of the user who followed someone and which I'm checking to be `NULL` to create a dynamic insert statement.

Whenever I call the procedure by passing the parameters, e.g.,

```
call populate_userfeed_after_following('joe', 'rocky'); 
#joe follows rocky
```

I get an error,

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

I would appreciate if you point out the mistake in my code.

Comment: You cannot do that, I suggest a user defined variable

Comment: So the `last_tweet` will be a user-defined variable like `SET @last_tweet = NULL; ` and then check if it is null by using `if (@like_tweet is NULL) then` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @P.Salmon pointed out, use of local variables (using DECLARE statement) would not work in this situation. So I corrected the code to use session variables or user-defined variables (using SET statement) and rewrote it.

The following logic works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `populate_userfeed_after_following`(IN username varchar(20), IN following_username varchar(20))
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE last_tweet timestamp default null;
    -- DECLARE following_id int;
    
    SET @following_id = 0;
    SET @last_tweet = NULL;
    
    SET @followingId_tweet = CONCAT('SELECT id from users where username=\'', following_username, '\' into @following_id');
    SET @timestamp_tweet = CONCAT('SELECT timestamp FROM userfeed_', username, ' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 into @last_tweet');
    
    PREPARE followingIdQuery FROM @followingId_tweet;
    EXECUTE followingIdQuery; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE followingIdQuery;
    
    PREPARE timestamp_tweetQuery FROM @timestamp_tweet;
    EXECUTE timestamp_tweetQuery; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE timestamp_tweetQuery;
    
    IF (@last_tweet is NULL) THEN
        SET @insert_statement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO userfeed_', username, '(tweet_id) SELECT id from tweets
        WHERE author=@following_id
        LIMIT 200');
    ELSE
        SET @insert_statement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO userfeed_', username, '(tweet_id) SELECT id from tweets
        WHERE author=@following_id and timestamp > @last_tweet');
    END IF;
    
    PREPARE insertQuery FROM @insert_statement;
    EXECUTE insertQuery; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE insertQuery;
    
END
```

The initial error was due to the select statement where I was using the value passed in the parameter to create a dynamic SQL statement and the line below that where `SET @timestamp_tweet` was used. The correct way to do that was to use prepared statements instead.